# JQuery - How to identify previously selected buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scenario:

A simple html page exists with few buttons on Top (e.g. day, week) and BOTTOM (filter1 and filter2) of the page and Graph on center.

The graph displays a data based on selected filters.

Problem:

when user selects the filter2 I need to know what the user selected previously on TOP buttons so that the data can be displayed accordingly.

I'm using global variable to track the last selected buttons. This means lots of switch statements. I'm wondering if this is the most elegant way to solve this issue or is there any magic. function exist on Jquery.

Comment: @Norse, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Create an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ And post the link. It will help others find an answer to your problem.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to include (at least a cut-down version of) your code directly in the question, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the top buttons have `class="topButton"` and the filter buttons have `class="filterButton"` and all buttons have unique ids, then the jQuery will look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var topButtons = $(".topButton").on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
            id = $this.attr('id');
        if($this.hasClass('selected')) { return; }
        topButtons.removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        //perform click action here
    });

    $('.filterButton').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
            id = $this.attr('id'),
            selectedTopButtonId = $('.topButton').filter('.selected').attr('id');
        //perform filter action here
    });
});
```

In both cases, the variable `id` lets you know which button was clicked.

By setting `class="selected"` on the selected top button, you can style the button and have something to test without needing to resort to a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use `data` on the elements themselves.

```
<button id="day" class="graph-button" data-state="off">Day</button>
<button id="week" class="graph-button" data-state="off">Week</button>
<!-- graph here -->
<button id="filter1" class="graph-button" data-state="off">Filter 1</button>
<button id="filter2" class="graph-button" data-state="off">Filter 2</button>
```

Then you could have some jQuery something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.graph-button').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var state = $(this).data('state'),
            newState = state == 'off' ? 'on' : 'off',
            onButtons = [];

        $(this).data('state', newState);

        $('.graph-button[data-state="on"]').each(function(i, el){
            onButtons.push(this.id);
        });

        // updateGraphWith(onButtons);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mVchr, can't use HTML5 attributes.

Comment: Well, you don't have to add the attributes to the HTML, you can just use `jQuery.data()`